# bird identification by its singing

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

What bird is singing on background in this video?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ckFIDeanJgg

Comment: First bird sounds at about 0:18

Answer (score 0):

The bird singing at the beginning sec. 0:18 is a Nightingale (*Luscinia megarhynchos*). A recording with the same beginning is here http://www.xeno-canto.org/379628

[image]